# Fit the entire large image inside the fixed crop window in android (scaling out like nocrop app)

Tags: java, android, image, crop

I have an image which has height greater than its width. I want to achieve something like user can pinch zoom out(or scale out) to fit the whole image inside a cropping window having a fixed aspect ratio (for eg: 16:9). If there is any empty space after zooming out then it should be filled with a default colour like black or white. It should work just like nocrop app for Instagram does, but here the cropped image won't be a square image. I am open to using any android libraries also if it can fix the issue.

Something like 
[image: scale out the image and fill colour in borders]